# Filter log lines within a 10 minute interval

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have below lines in my dummy.text file. I would like to filter these data using bash script or awk.

```
Jul 28 15:05:47 *   aaa has joined
Jul 28 15:07:47 *   bbb has joined
Jul 28 15:08:41 *   ccc has joined
Jul 28 15:13:32 *   ddd has joined
Jul 28 15:14:40 *   eee has joined
```

For example, let's say `aaa` has joined the session at time `15:05:47` and `ccc` joined the session at `15:08:47`. I want to get the line who has joined equal/after `15:00:00` and before `15:10:00`. The expected result would be:

```
Jul 28 15:05:47 *   aaa has joined
Jul 28 15:07:47 *   bbb has joined
Jul 28 15:08:41 *   ccc has joined
```

Side note: after getting the expected output I'm looking to write cron job in which this data will be forward to mail.

Answer (score 0):

One way :

```
awk -F'[ :]' '$3 == 15 && $4 >= 0 && $4 <= 10' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat dummy.text | awk '$3>="15:05:47" && $3<="15:08:47" {print}'
```

Comment: Note that `cat | awk` is a UUoC (Useless Use of Cat); you could supply the filename as an argument to `awk`.  I think your conditions are a little too specific, though there is the germ of the correct idea (compare column 3 with the ends of the time range).

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the 10-minute interval as 15:00:00 up to but not including 15:10:00, then:

```
awk -v start=15:00:00 -v end=15:10:00 '$3 >= start && $3 < end'
```

If you decide you want to omit the final `:00` for the seconds from the times, then:

```
awk -v start=15:00 -v end=15:10 '$3 >= start ":00" && $3 < end ":00"'
```

Both of these will report on entries in the time interval on any day.  If you want to restrict the date, then you can apply further conditions (on `$1` and `$2`).

If you calculate the start and end values in shell variables, then:

```
start=$(…)    # Calculate start time hh:mm
end=$(…)      # Calculate end time hh:mm
awk -v start="$start" -v end="$end" '$3 >= start ":00" && $3 < end ":00"'
```